# objective C, iOS: not calling alloc or init on a subview

Tags: objective-c, ios, view, initialization, memory-management

I am currently running the following code as part of a simple test iPad program.  I've declared "viewController" as a property.  In all other examples I've seen involving subviews, I've been required to alloc and init the viewController, but here it works fine.  Any ideas?

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    // Why does this work without allocating or initializing viewController?
    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the typical boilerplate code Apple supplies with the iOS templates. In these projects the viewController is defined in the `MainWindow` NIB. This NIB is loaded very early in the process of starting the app. The viewController is allocated in the NIB loading process, and `initWithNibName:bundle:` is then called. The NIB loading process then connects the initialized object to the view controller's  `IBOutlet` of the app delegate.

Comment: Thanks!  That is indeed what is going on.